# Orthogonality of homogeneous chaoses.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, wiener-measure

### Some notation:

Let $B(t)$ be a brownian motion, let $\mathcal F^B$ the sigma algebra generated by $\{B(t):a\leq t\leq b\}$.

Let $L_B^2(\Omega)$ be the Hilbert space of square-integrable functions that are measurable with respect to $\mathcal F^B$.

Assume $J_1$ is defined to be the closure of the linear space spanned by constant functions and polynomial chaos of degree $\leq 1$.

Now define $K_1$  in order to satisfy $$J_1=K_1\oplus \mathbb R.$$

Now suppose we have a deterministic function $f\in L^2[a,b]$, $I(f)=\int_a^b f(s) dB(s)$.

### I am trying to prove the following assertion.

> Then it follows from direct calculations that
>   $I(f)^2-\|f\|_{L^2[a,b]}^2$ is orthogonal to $\mathbb R$ and $K_1$.

---

To prove that it's orthogonal to $\mathbb R$ lets write
$$\langle  I(f)^2-\|f\|_{L^2[a,b]}^2, \alpha\rangle=\alpha\cdot\mathbb E\big[I(f)^2-\|f\|_{L^2[a,b]}^2\big] , \alpha\in\mathbb R$$
This equals $0$ since the Wiener integral is an isometry.

Now in order to show that it's orthogonal to $K_1$ I need to show that

$$\int_{\Omega}(I(f)^2-\|f\|_{L^2[a,b]}^2)\cdot g dP =0$$

Since by assumption any $g\in K_1$ is orthogonal to $\mathbb R$, and $\|f\|_{L^2[a,b]}^2\in\mathbb R$ the previous is equivalent to show that

$$\int_{\Omega} I(f)^2\cdot g dP=\mathbb E\big[I(f)^2\cdot g\big]=0$$

Here's where I get stuck, I know that $g$ is some linear combination of Wiener integrals, but I am not able to see how to show the expectations of the product is actually zero.

If for instance $g=I(f)$ then it's easy to show that the expectations equals zero, the same if $g$ is independent from $I(f)$ (I don't think this is possible).

I would be glad to receive some guidance.
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it the case that $g$ lies in the first homogenous chaos (which I think is what you are denoting by $K_1$) and hence is automatically of the form $I(h)$ for some $h$? (for clarity, I didn't downvote and I'm a bit confused by the downvote. My only guess is that it's a bit unclear what the question is right now. It might help to make it clear that you are trying to prove the thing in the yellow box)

Comment: @RhysSteele yes it's the case, but anyway I don't believe $I(h)$ is independent from $I(f)^2$ in general, so it's the expectation of the product of a chi-square random variable and a guassian random variable

Comment: @RhysSteele Indeed,  maybe is not clear what I am asking, and it may be very trivial for some users, but honestly I don't really understand this compulsion some users have to downvote without any actual feedback.

Comment: It's more helpful to think of it as the expectation of the product of $3$ Gaussians. You may then be interested in Wick's formula for the expectation of products of Gaussian's (otherwise known as [Isserlis' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem))

Comment: @RhysSteele Oh nice, and in this case the three r.v. $I(f), I(f), I(h)$ are jointly gaussian because any linear combination is again gaussian by the linearity of the Wiener integral? If you put together a small answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g$ is in the first homogenous chaos, there is a deterministic $h$ such that $g = I(h)$. This means that from your work it is enough to show that 
$$\mathbb{E}[I(f)^2 I(h)] = 0$$

This will follow immediately from the Wick Formula for moments of a multivariate Gaussian (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem)) as soon as we check that $(I(f),I(f),I(h))$ is a centered Gaussian vector. This is immediate since $$\alpha I(f) + \beta I(h) = I(\alpha f + \beta h)$$
which is centered Gaussian since $\alpha f + \beta h$ is deterministic.